# TFS - Moved files showing 'Add files to Source Control' when already in source control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Should I be worried that TFS is still telling me to ‘Add files to Source Control’ when they already are having moved files from one project to another in the same solution?

To provide some background, I got multiple projects in my solution. I needed to move a complete folder structure and the files from one project to another and sit them in a new directory.

So for example

Moving contents of ‘Website.Assets’ - $/Adam/Website/Website.Assets

To a new folder named ‘Assets’ in another project - $/Adam/Website/Website.App/Assets

I added the new folder ‘Assets’ via source control explorer and then added it into the project via solution explorer.

Having then moved the folders/files from the one project to the other via the move functionality in source control explore, then added to the project and checked in. The project now states there are still files to be added to source control, when there isn’t.

It's only when I right kick on the new parent folder 'Assets' that I see the message 'Add files to Source Control' non of the files that were moved from the other project to this project show this message.

Is this something to even worry about? If so any suggestions on fixing it?